# Artifacts after the Boolean Modifier

Tags: modifiers, artifacts, toon-shading

Greetings dear 3D artists! I am trying to create a shape to organize a collection of PBR materials.
I add a UV-Sphere (Segments: 128, Rings: 64). Then I apply the **Solidify Modifier** (Thickness: 0.25 m). I add a quadrangular prism. After combining these objects, I apply the **Boolean Modifier** (Mode: Difference). After turning on the **Shade Smooth** mode, distortion artifacts appear on the sphere.
What can I do in this situation? Do I need to merge the extra vertices manually, or is there another way? (Blender v2.93).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your sphere, just check the autosmooth checkbox here:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: OK. Many thanks! Everything works.

Comment: You are welcome